# How to compute prorata calculation in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'd like to do a `prorata` calculation in PL/SQL but I have no clue how to do so.

Here my exemple :

```
ID  class  Wages  Premium
1     A    15000     250
2     A    10000      0
```

I'd like to compute premium on a prorata basis within class, i.e. for every ID in each CLASS, I'd like to compute the premium on a prorata basis with respect to Wages.

Here, for ID 1, 
it would :

```
premium = (15000 *sum(premium))/(sum(wages)) = (15000 * 250)/(25000) = 150
```

Thus, for ID 2 :

```
premium = (10000 * 250)/(25000) = 100
```

Obviously I have to do that on more voluminous data... But I haven't done much PL/SQL till now...

I may add that I MUST do it throgh an update statement...

Please could you help me ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient method would be to use ratio_to_report(), which is often strangely ignored.

```
select id,
       premium,
       sum(premium) over (partition by class) *
         ratio_to_report(wages) over (partition by class) prorated_premium
from   my_table
```

For an update I would look at:

```
update (query from above)
set premium = prorated_premium
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily calculate the new premium values with analytic functions:

```
create table prorata_test as
select 1 id,
       'A' class,
       15000 wages,
       250 premium
from dual
union all
select 2 id,
       'A' class,
       10000 wages,
       0 premium
from dual
union all
select 3 id,
       'B' class,
       10000 wages,
       50 premium
from dual;

select id,
       class,
       wages,
       premium,
       sum(wages) over (partition by class) tot_wages,
       sum(premium) over (partition by class) tot_premium,
       wages * sum(premium) over (partition by class) / sum(wages) over (partition by class) new_premium
from   prorata_test;

        ID CLASS      WAGES    PREMIUM  TOT_WAGES TOT_PREMIUM NEW_PREMIUM
---------- ----- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- -----------
         1 A          15000        250      25000         250         150
         2 A          10000          0      25000         250         100
         3 B          10000         50      10000          50          50
```

So you can see that the analytic sum functions that calculate the tot_wages and to_premium columns sum up the values across each class (which is what we partitioned by (aka grouped by)), and you can therefore just use them in the new_premium calculation.

To store the new premium value, you would use a MERGE statement with the above query as the source data set, like so:

```
merge into prorata_test tgt
using (select id,
              class,
              wages,
              premium,
              wages * sum(premium) over (partition by class) / sum(wages) over (partition by class) new_premium
       from   prorata_test) src
  on (tgt.id = src.id)
when matched then
update set tgt.premium = src.new_premium;

commit;

select *
from   prorata_test
order by id;

        ID CLASS      WAGES    PREMIUM
---------- ----- ---------- ----------
         1 A          15000        150
         2 A          10000        100
         3 B          10000         50
```

N.B. I am assuming here that ID is the primary key (or at least, that it's unique across the table!).

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
with data(class, sum_pre, sum_wage) as (
    select class, sum(Premium), sum(Wages)
    from tbl
    group by class
)
select t.ID, t.class
    t.Wages * s.sum_pre/ s.sum_wage as val
from tbl t
join data s on s.class = t.class
```

For Update

```
MERGE
INTO tbl t
USING (
    with data(class, sum_pre, sum_wage) as (
        select class, sum(Premium), sum(Wages)
        from tbl
        group by class
    )
    select t.ID
        t.Wages * s.sum_pre/ s.sum_wage as val
    from tbl t
    join data s on s.class = t.class
) x
ON (x.ID = t.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET premium = x.val;
```